# smallest and largest eigenvalue of discretized operator $-d^2/dx^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

In 1D, the second order derivative operator $-d^2/dx^2$ can be discretized as, using Matlab

```
n = 501; h = 1/(n-1);
A = 1/h*spdiags(ones(n,1)*[-1 2 -1],-1:1,n,n); 
[V,D]=eig(full(A));
```

Now I am wondering about what information do the smallest(0.0196) and largest(2000) eigenvalues give?

how is it related to the discretization?

Comment: Just a minor thing: if $h$ is the grid-spacing it should be $1/h^2$.

Comment: @Winther depends on you prefer FEM or FDM, of course here some BCs need to be imposed :)

Comment: Fair point:) I'm such a FDM extremist!

Comment: The eigenfunction with the smallest eigenvalue (roughly $y_i \simeq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sin(\pi i/n)$) is the solution to $-y'' = \lambda y$ with the largest wavelength (only one half wavelength over the interval) that can be resolved on the grid. The largest eigenvalue corresponds to the solution with the smallest wavelength ($n/2$ wavelengths over the interval, and $e = 4n$ for large $n$) that can be resolved on the grid.

Comment: ...I forgot to add: the smallest eigenvalue is $e \simeq \frac{\pi^2}{n}$ (for large $n$).